# Запретить ввод в input пробелы, пока не введен другой символ

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения, input, валидация

у меня есть форма с текстовым полем, никаких ограничений на возможные вводимые символы нет. Но я хочу сделать так, чтобы нельзя было вводить строку, состоящую из одних пробелов, либо начинающуюся с пробела.

Я нашел где-то вариант регулярного выражения и использовал атрибут pattern

```
<input type="text" name="name" pattern="^[^\s]+(\s.*)?$">
```

Однако при таком способе строка будет проверяться при отправке формы, но писать в поле все равно можно что угодно.

А я бы хотел, чтобы вообще физически нельзя было вводить в поле пробелы, пока не веден хоть один другой символ. Я подумал здесь можно использовать JavaScript c атрибутом событий oninput, но я со скриптом практически не знаком, та что не знаю, как это провернуть.

Comment: Нет, не надо физически запрещать что-то вводить - это тупиковый путь, который плохо работает на мобильных устройствах, тяжело делать и вообще это не юзер френдли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подтверждаю первый комментарий, но если прям уж очень хочется так сделать, то вот рабочий метод:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('foo');

input.oninput = () => {
  if(input.value.charAt(0) === ' ') {
    input.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="foo" type="text" />
```

Comment: зачем `chartAt` использовать, если можно просто `value[0]`?

Comment: @Дмытрык, это всего лишь ещё один и возможных вариантов.

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую.

Comment: И за предостережение спасибо, я не думал о таком. Просто я не хотел делать какие-то предупреждения, в случае ошибки, по стилю это не впишется у меня. А без этого юзеру может быть не понятно, почему форма не отправилась. Вот я и подумал, что лучше вообще запретить возможность ввода.

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но вы не запретили события: вставка из буфера обмена, автокомплит в мобильных а также drag&frop. К тому же, у вас запрет на ввод пробела первым символом, т.е. если сначала ввести "123" а потом поставить пробел перед "1" то все сотрется.